# c# change Registered User and the Organization in Windows?

Tags: c#, windows

how to change the Registered User and the Organization in Windows (XP and higher) using C#?
I know how to retrieve them, but not sure how to update/change them!

cheers

Answer (score 1):

The information for those data are located in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
```

section of the registry under the keys

```
RegisteredOrganization
```

and

```
RegisteredOwner
```

You can write a C# app to edit these values and you are set.